# SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock

Tags: mysql, deadlock

Hello can someone help me to solve this deadlock? This is database output:

```
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2018-03-07 19:18:21 2b9dc1921700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 13905343008, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 51 lock struct(s), heap size 6544, 34 row lock(s), undo log entries 47
MySQL thread id 12395, OS thread handle 0x2b326700, query id 307443 
INSERT INTO `promo` (`trans_id`, `offer_id`, `item`, `use_count`, `value`, `ctime`, `mtime`, `transaction_item_id`) VALUES ('32643952', '13182856', '[59446282] aafr', '1', '-30.0000', '1520450301', '1520450301', '59446282')
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 14003 page no 46310 n bits 280 index `FK_pu_ti` of table `b`.`promo_use` trx id 139sd43008 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 13905343033, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
62 lock struct(s), heap size 6544, 50 row lock(s), undo log entries 48
MySQL thread id 12560297, OS thread handle 0x2b9dc1921700, query id 
INSERT INTO `promo` (`trans_id`, `offer_id`, `item`, `use_count`, `value`, `ctime`, `mtime`, `transaction_item_id`) VALUES ('32643953', '13605122', '[59446286] fdgdfg', '1', '-30.0000', '1520450301', '1520450301', '59446286')
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 14003 page no 46310 n bits 280 index `FK_pu_ti` of table `bazu`.`promo_use` trx id 13905343033 lock mode S
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 14003 page no 46310 n bits 280 index `FK_pu_ti` of table `b`.`promo` trx id 133123 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)Updating promo
```

How this is related to FK_pu_ti? Those are two different threats, is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: What's there to "solve"? Deadlocks aren't meant to be "solved", they can't be solved.

Comment: so from this log second insert happens while table is locked?